# Can i customize windows log in screen as per my requirement?

Tags: windows, customization, gina

I just want to integrate windows with my already developed system.

I need login screen that contains window user name And when  i click on login button some other page or popup should ask me my system user name and password along with one button.
without my system user name and pass word user can not login to computer.

i just wanted to know that is it possible or not.

If it is possible than give me a way please..

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to modify the main Windows login screen? Or just use Windows credentials in another app? The latter can be done with LDAP.

Comment: yes i want to modify main Windows login screen...@ Danny Beckett

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible [any more], bar modifying the background image, e.g. http://www.techspot.com/guides/224-change-logon-screen-windows7/

Comment: I have read something about GINA but i don't know what is it exactly.